# Created a Function in Python that I know works by itself but want to use it to iterate through and calculate a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Have created the function below which does work when I pass values to it, I want to use it to calculate the a newly created column in my dataframe. but I've got no idea what to put after the '=' when adding the new_column.

```
    def home_team(home_odds,draw_odds,away_odds, full_time_result):
    if full_time_result == 'H':
        return 2 - home_odds
    elif full_time_result == 'D':
        return 3 - draw_odds
    elif full_time_result == 'A':
        return 1 - away_odds
    end



    df['new_column'] =
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is not so clear. How home_odds,draw_odds,away_odds defined? What is the full_time_result? Without seeing your columns in data it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your function in such a way that it can be **applied**
to each row.

This function should have **one** parameter, called e.g. *row*.

References to fields of the current row should have a form like
*row.column_name*.

So your function can be changed e.g. to:

```
def home_team(row):
    if row.full_time_result == 'H':
        return 2 - row.home_odds
    elif row.full_time_result == 'D':
        return 3 - row.draw_odds
    elif row.full_time_result == 'A':
        return 1 - row.away_odds
```

(the final *end* in your code sample is not needed).

Then apply this function to each row and save the result as a new column:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(home_team, axis=1)
```

To test this code, I created the following DataFrame:

```
   home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds full_time_result
0        0.5        0.4        0.1                H
1        0.2        0.6        0.2                D
2        0.1        0.3        0.6                A
```

After application of the above function the result is:

```
   home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds full_time_result  new_column
0        0.5        0.4        0.1                H         1.5
1        0.2        0.6        0.2                D         2.4
2        0.1        0.3        0.6                A         0.4
```

If your column names are different from the above example, change column
names in the function accordingly.

Comment: thank you, makes complete sense and this worked perfectly